# Need to change Uppercase to lowercase using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Right now I can use this with some success but I cant get it to work recursively? Any help would be awesome! I have been googling all day to find a solution and I havent found anything else that works.

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%%f" "%%f")
```

it has been suggested to do this but I've had no success.

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l/b/a-d/s') do (rename "%%f" "%%f")
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer to your question http://superuser.com/a/79277

Answer (score 1):

#### The rename command only takes a file name as the second parameter.

```
C:\>rename /?
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.
```

Here are the corrected rename parameters

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /l/b/a-d/s') do rename "%%~fF" "%%~nxF"
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. as %%~nxF (and %%~fF) restore the case from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Command Prompt.
Go to the folder with the `cd` command (eg.: `cd "path of your folder"`).
Open a powershell by typing: `powershell`.
Then input this:

```
get-childitem -recurse | Where {-Not $_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName.ToLower()}
```